# Can this be done in 1 iteration instead of 2 and will it solve multiple enumeration issue?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, json.net

I am having no issues with this method; it does return the dictionary intended. BUT... I see two problems I'd like to solve if possible.

1. I could be wrong but I'm fairly certain the two iterations of tokenResponse aren't necessary (first to get the list of symbols and the second to build the dictionary) and it can be done in one LINQ statement. I just can't get it right having tried a dozen or so iterations trying to build one statement to return the proper Dictionary.
2. Resharper is giving me the "Possible multiple enumeration" warning for both tokenResponse iterations.

I have tried changing both the interface I am using for the method that is calling this method and the underlying type to IList, ICollection, IReadOnlyCollection etc... but can never get the whole change to work, as it does using IEnumerable. There is always at least on type conversion error noted by VS 2019

One can never be sure but I don't believe the multiple enumeration issue would result in bad data return as the json it is iterating through is relatively simple.

Any help appreciated.

**Method**

```
public static IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<IEquityData>> CreateDictionaryOfEquityDataObjects(
        IEnumerable<JToken> tokenResponse)
    {
        var tempDict = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<IEquityData>>();

        var symbols = tokenResponse.Select(m => m.SelectToken("symbol"))
                                   .Distinct()
                                   .ToList();

        foreach (var symbol in symbols)
        {
           var lst = tokenResponse.Select(token => new EquityHistoricalDataDto
            {
                Symbol = symbol.Value<string>(),
                TradeDate = token["date"].Value<DateTime>(),
                Open = token["open"].Value<decimal>(),
                High = token["high"].Value<decimal>(),
                Low = token["low"].Value<decimal>(),
                Close = token["close"].Value<decimal>(),
                Volume = token["volume"].Value<double>()
            }).Where(m => m.Symbol == symbol.Value<string>()).ToList();
           tempDict.Add(symbol.ToString(), lst);
        }
       
        return tempDict;
    }
```

**Json Sample**

```
{
  "open": 387.99,
  "high": 388.31,
  "low": 368.04,
  "close": 371.38,
  "volume": 49251108.0,      
  "symbol": "AAPL",
  "exchange": "XNAS",
  "date": "2020-07-23T00:00:00+0000"
},
{
  "open": 3098.27,
  "high": 3098.27,
  "low": 2970.0,
  "close": 2986.55,
  "volume": 5656906.0,     
  "symbol": "AMZN",
  "exchange": "XNAS",
  "date": "2020-07-23T00:00:00+0000"
}
rest removed for brevity
```

}

**Code to create JToken array**

```
var response = await sqr.GetHttpContentAsync(url);
var responseArray = JObject.Parse(response.Item1).SelectToken("data").ToArray();
```

Here is what the response looks like in VS 2019 JSON Visualizer
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It seems, that you'll need a `GroupBy`. What is the relationship between `IEquityData` and `EquityHistoricalDataDto`?

Comment: `.Where(m => m.Symbol == symbol.Value<string>())` this does not filter anything, as `Symbol = symbol.Value<string>()`. You compare the same thing to itself. And not only that, you assign symbol to data of different symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by `symbol` token and then map the result into dictionary using [`ToDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToDictionary__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__) method

```cs
var dict = tokenResponse
    .GroupBy(m => m["symbol"].Value<string>())
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(token => (IEquityData)new EquityHistoricalDataDto
    {
        Symbol = g.Key,
        TradeDate = token["date"].Value<DateTime>(),
        Open = token["open"].Value<decimal>(),
        High = token["high"].Value<decimal>(),
        Low = token["low"].Value<decimal>(),
        Close = token["close"].Value<decimal>(),
        Volume = token["volume"].Value<double>()
    }
).ToList().AsEnumerable());
```

The result dictionary type will `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<EquityHistoricalDataDto>>` (because [`IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.idictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1) has invariant generic parameters). It's not fully clear, why do you have `IEnumerable<IEquityData>` in return type and what is the relationship between `IEquityData` and `EquityHistoricalDataDto`. If `EquityHistoricalDataDto` implements `IEquityData`, you may add an explicit cast to interface in `Select` method or after that.

Comment: ...Thanks, not sure why but the original query is returning 100 items for each symbol, as it should be. Your query is returning between 14 and 23 items for each symbol, so somewhere in the symbol look up its not finding all instances of that symbol.

Comment: Also,I had to modify your query to Symbol = g.Key.Value<string>() as Values was producing an error in VS ". Leaving it as Values... VS wants me to either call ToString on that, which doesn't work. It produces a null result. Or change the property type for Symbol to IEnumerable<string> which is not doable

Comment: Also, the reason for IEnumerable<IEquityData> in return type, is that is what the calling method is expecting. EquityHistoricalDataDto is implemented from IEquityData and is done so as I use three different service API's to retrieve the data and I need the methods to be useable regardless of the API I request from.

Comment: Your edit still produces the same result, all 100 objects for each symbol are not returned. Thanks for the help. Ill likely leave it as is.

Comment: Seems like the return type might be better suited as an ILookup<> since your dictionary is expected to hold an enumerable of values per key. Also I think that the reason your version is returning 100 objects is because as the source you are requerying `tokenRepsonse` which does not have the `Distinct` applied to it.. But I'm a little unsure.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Thanks, that's a good point. Using `ToList().AsEnumerable()` with dictionary also can be an option. As for the number of records, OP didn't mention where data come from

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski sorry I was more addressing the OP since they can't figure out the discrepancy in counts. And since we don't see the source it's hard to be sure what's going on

Comment: the full response has 100 days of data per symbol

Comment: If you need `.GroupBy().ToDictionary()` then most of the time you really need `.ToLookup()`

Answer (score 1):

Does this solve your problem?

```
public static IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<IEquityData>> CreateDictionaryOfEquityDataObjects(IEnumerable<JToken> tokenResponse)
{
    var query =
        from tr in tokenResponse
        let dto = new EquityHistoricalDataDto
        {
            Symbol = tr["symbol"].Value<string>(),
            TradeDate = tr["date"].Value<DateTime>(),
            Open = tr["open"].Value<decimal>(),
            High = tr["high"].Value<decimal>(),
            Low = tr["low"].Value<decimal>(),
            Close = tr["close"].Value<decimal>(),
            Volume = tr["volume"].Value<double>()
        }
        group dto by dto.Symbol;

    return query.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Cast<IEquityData>());
}
```

That gives me:

[image: dictionary]

Comment: @Enigmativity...Well your code certainly looked to me like it should work but is causing an error.  Cannot cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Extensions.Convert<T, U>(T token)
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Extensions.Value<T, U>(IEnumerable<T> value)
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Extensions.Value<U>(IEnumerable<JToken> value)
TradingAdvantage.Services.EquityDataService.Classes.ProcessResponseToObject+<>c.<CreateDictionaryOfEquityDataObjects>b__2_0(JToken tr) in ProcessResponseToObject.cs

                let dto = new MarketStackEquityHistoricalDataDto

Comment: @dinotom - Can you please show your code for creating the `IEnumerable<JToken> tokenResponse` from your JSON?

Comment: @Enigmativity...done including a screenshot of what the response looks like

Comment: @dinotom - Thank you. Can you please post a valid JSON sample that goes with that code?

Comment: @Enigmativity...you can download the json file here...https://batlgroupimages.blob.core.windows.net/accessibleimages/batlgroup/data/test.json

Comment: @dinotom - It certainly helps to have the full data and code. Thank you. I've updated my answer.